# Difference between rig and armature ? (and a few other beginner questions)

Tags: armature

I'm just getting my feet wet in Blender, but ran into a couple of things I can't get my head around. Following the tutorials and my own tryouts, it's possible to create a "skeleton" for the purpose of setting up poses. These skeletons have the appearance of long thin pyramids(-ish).

Because I don't have the skill to create a full model yet I downloaded a premade 'rigged' character. This guy's bones are represented just as lines. I can set him up in poses using that, is this different than armatures ?
I also am able to move him in crazy ways, if I move the leg bone away from the character the leg will stretch all the way across the world. Is it possible for Blender to "pull" the rest of the body along so the character stays the same height ? Does this have something to do with his rig being lines and not pyramids ?

Another question I have is that I created a plane with a video, the purpose is to use the video as backdrop to "rotoscope" the character's movements.
When the viewport is in render mode the video plays as intended. 
I would like this to happen aswell when the viewport is set to "Solid".
For now I only see the image when the object is selected, and also the video doesn't move along according to the selected frame (only in Render mode)

Comment: The lines for bones is just a viewing option that you can change in the bone settings. Click on the armature icon to find those settings. As for your second question, this is to do with parenting. In the Overlay panel, if you click on the plus icon, it'll show you the hierarchy of your bones. You'll see the bones towards the left are parents and the bones on the right underneath them (again use the plus sign to view what's underneath that bone) are their children bones. Include a master parent bone at the top to move your whole rig around.

Comment: Please ask only one question by post, it's easier to answer that way.